# alarm goes off as soon as i set it,please help me to remove it...?

Tags: android

*here is a scenario:*

suppose today right now the time is  9 am in the morning....

i set the alarm for 6 am **daily**,(note that the alarm time 6 am <9 am)

this is what happens

**1** the alarm rings  as soon as i set it(not required,i think that is because 6am <9am and hence the alarm rings for that day itslef as 6 am has already passed )

**2** the alarm goes off for the next days too (required)

so how can i stop **1** to happen ???

here is the code i am using

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            // 9 AM 
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, xhour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Reminder.this, 0,
                        intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, xhour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: that totally screws up the alarm,can you please tell me what was the logic behind it >

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please review, and try if it helps. Didn't see you used set method in the first place.

Comment: If the one I re-edited does not work, please post code how xhour and minutes variables are set.

Comment: well thank you for your help but i got it working,+1 for your time :D